# Linux secure boot automatic enrollement

Tags: linux, uefi

I'm able to enrolled a pub key with mokutil but my server must reboot and I have to manually enter password and navigate to UEFI to validate etc...

In case of the pub key change and the pub will change in 2 years, how it could be possible to enrolled by script or how to automatize a renew ?